# Multiple Field types of fields in Symfony2 Datatimepicker & filter

Tags: symfony

I'm trying  to work with the bundles :

[https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle)

https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle

So I've a filed of my form with to apply a filter acordin to this field

```
  ->add('fecha', 'filter_date_range');
```

Now I wanna add another parameter because this field is a data then I wanna see a datapicker so I need to apply another parameter here like

```
 ->add('fecha', 'filter_date_range collot_datetime');
```

But this not works so, are there some way to implements the both bundles in a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done out of the box - field can have only one type. 
If you need to customize form field type you can create your own: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html (based on these two)